# Configure lsp-mode to start the python server when in snakemake major mode

Tags: python, lsp-mode, python-lsp-server

I would like to know if it's possible to configure LSP mode to start the Python server when I work on a snakemake file (`snakemake-mode`), as I use heavily use Python in this mode also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an entry for snakemake files to the variable `lsp-language-id-configuration` variable. The variable `lsp-language-id-configuration` is defined in `lsp-mode.el`, and it maps files to major modes or file extensions to help decide which language server(s) to launch.

The following should work, add the snippet to your Emacs initialization file (e.g., `init.el` or `.emacs`).

```
(add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration '(snakemake-mode . "python"))
```